# how to keep a column updated?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I create the following tables:

```
create table AandB (
        code              varchar(9),
        total             number,
        CONSTRAINT pk_code PRIMARY KEY (code)
);

create table A (
        codeA              varchar(9),
        numberA              number,
        CONSTRAINT pk_codeA PRIMARY KEY (codeA)
);

create table B (
        codeB              varchar(9),
        numberB            number,
        CONSTRAINT pk_codeB PRIMARY KEY (codeB)

);
```

I inserted the following datas:

```
insert into AandB(code) values('0x1');
insert into AandB(code) values('0x2');
insert into AandB(code) values('0x3');

insert into A(codeA, numberA) values('0x1',5);
insert into A(codeA, numberA) values('0x2',6);
insert into A(codeA, numberA) values('0x3',1);

insert into B(codeB, numberB) values('0x1',8);
insert into B(codeB, numberB) values('0x2',10);
insert into B(codeB, numberB) values('0x3',12);
```

The question is: how to keep the table "AandB" updated with a trigger?.

I use the following query to add both tables:

```
UPDATE AandB ab
SET ab.total = (SELECT a.numberA + b.numberB
                FROM A
                INNER JOIN B
                 ON(a.codeA = b.codeB)
                WHERE a.codeA = ab.code)
```

Now, 0X1 = 13. But if I update Table A:

```
update A set numberA=10 where codeA='0x1';
```

Now, 0X1 should be 0x1=18

Answer (score 1):

Create a view instead, will always be up to date!

```
create view AandB (code, total) as
SELECT a.code, a.numberA + b.numberB
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON (a.codeA = b.codeB)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [trigger](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/triggers.htm) which will be executed with each update on the column "number" of both tables "A" and "B". The body of your trigger can be same as your update statement:

```
UPDATE AandB ab
SET ab.total = (SELECT a.numberA + b.numberB
                FROM A
                INNER JOIN B
                 ON(a.codeA = b.codeB)
                WHERE a.codeA = ab.code)
```

For better performance you can add a "WHERE" clause to it as the following:

(For the trigger of table A)

```
WHERE ab.code = :NEW.numberA
```

(For the trigger of table B)

```
WHERE ab.code = :NEW.numberB
```